# Android Firebase Chat Notifications

Tags: android, service, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an app for Android that requires a chat section. I need to be able to do notifications for new chat messages as well as show live updates of number of new chats (in a toolbar). The way I've implemented the chat portion itself is almost identical to the one here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

In broad strokes, the chat Activity connects to a child in the database and monitors it for updates. The updates come from chats being pushed to that child. My question is, could I use a service which does the same? Could I build a services that keeps a connection with Firebase and watches for updates in a certain child of the database so I can pull my updates and notifications from it?

Comment: It should be possible to put the database connection in a service. But what's the purpose of that?

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a way to be able to do notifications for these chats that doesn't revolve around a third party service, and is able to update the app if it's running. Is there a better way to do this I'm not thinking of? I can only find very limited info online about how push notifications are done in Firebase unless they're pushed from the Firebase console.

Comment: Sending updates to the users of your app when the app is not active should be done through Firebase Notifications (which has a web page where you can send the notifications from) or [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (which has an API that you can call from your app server).